# Trigger with update

Tags: pl-sql

Eu tenho uma tabela `emp` com `salary`, `id`, e `job` e adicionei um novo valor de coluna nesta coluna. Vou atualizar quando o empregado receber um aumento. Criei uma tabela de suporte onde tenho id , salary,date e new_salary eu criei a primeira `trigger` quando houver um `insert` na tabela a `trigger` dispara e insere na tabela suporte (está funcionando até aqui), depois eu preciso atualizar a tabela `emp` com `value = new salary - salary`. Eu compilei o `trigger` mas quando executo `update` da tabela `emp` aparece `error: ora-06519: active autonomous transition` e se eu levar o pragma o erro muda para:  `ora-04091:the table emp_log is mutant`

> **Texto original para consulta:**
>   I have a table emp with salary, id, and job and add a new column value in this column I will do update when employee receive an increase.
>   I created a table support when I have id , salary,date and new_salary
>   I created a first trigger when a Insert in table emp the trigger shoots and insert in table support (it's working until here) , after I need update the table emp with value = new salary - salary.
>   I compiled trigger but when I execute update on emp show error:
>   ora-06519: active autonomous transition
>   and if I take pragma change error to: ora-04091:the table emp_log is mutant

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER new_salario_emp
AFTER INSERT
   ON emp_log
   FOR EACH ROW
   --
 DECLARE
 Pragma Autonomous_Transaction;
 --
 BEGIN
 --
 update emp_log set old_salario = :new.sal - :new.old_salario where empno = 
:new.empno;
 --
END;
```

Comment: Talvez não tenha reparado (o que é estranho), mas estamos no [pt.so], então pode (e deve) fazer a pergunta em português. Aproveite e já faça o [tour] e leia o guia de [ask]. Se restar alguma dúvida, acesse a [help] e/ou o [meta].

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi: o seu trigger não deveria ser na tabela original (EMP) e não na tabela de suporte (EMP_LOG)?

Me parece que vc deseja guardar apenas o ultimo salário anterior a alteração. É isso?
Então na inclusão de uma linha em EMP você deve incluir uma linha na tabela EMP_LOG E na alteração de SALARY em EMP você que atualizar EMP_LOG.

Se for iisso, crie um TRIGGER AFTER INSERT em EMP e inclua a linha em EMP_LOG. Crie um TRIGGER AFTER UPDATE SALARY em EMP e atualize a tabela EMP_LOG.